# "X" is not defined - using "For loop" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm currently learning javascript loop and right now i'm trying to make an exemple using the "For" loop but as i'm trying it keep telling me "longString is not defined".
the result i'm trying to have is to print 6 A like this "AAAAAA"
here is the code:

```
var longString = A;

for (var longString = A; longstring < 6; longString = longString + A) {
  console.log(longString);
}
```

i'm sure the solution is simple but as a totally beginner i can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: longstring is different from longString. closing as typo

Comment: Please check the for a loop. you have a typo in the second word. longstring should be longString.

Comment: As well as the `longstring` typo, it’s worth calling out another change that each of the existing answers make: using `"A"` in place of `A`. `"A"` is a string containing the letter A; `A` is a reference to another variable `A`. If your code never assigned `A` like `var A = "something";`, that would be another reason why its `longString` would be `undefined` after `var longString = A`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your break condition:

```
var longString = ""; 

for (longString = "A"; longstring < 6; longString = longString + "A") { 
   // Note the lowercase 's' ^
}
console.log(longString);
```

Also, if you want to get the length of a string, you can use `string.length`:

```
longString.length < 6;
```

Comment: He wants to print 6(AAAAAAA) not a right-angle triangle of the code. Print the longString outside the loop.

Comment: @AayushSaini Good catch, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this what you want?

```js
var str = ""

for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  str += "A"
}

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the below code prints "AAAAAA" in one line.

```
var longString = 'A'
var str = ''

for (var i = 0; i<6;  i+=1){

  str = longString + str

}

console.log(str)
```